# IOS Difference Between uiview and uilabel for drawing

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

So i have a weird problem when im trying to draw in a custom class that has a subclass of a uiview the lines are thick and fuzzy but when i change the subclass to a uilabel it looks smooth and thin. Just curious are there different default settings enabled for this to occur and if so what are they ?

cant post screens yet

Thanks in advance

Update:
Relevent code note no changes are being made between changing of the subclass

```js
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);
// CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx,YES);
// CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

CGContextSetShadow(ctx, CGSizeMake(0, 3), 2);

CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 1, 0);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(ctx, 5, self.frame.size.height - 10, 15, self.frame.size.height - 1, 30, self.frame.size.height - 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.frame.size.width - 30, self.frame.size.height - 1);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(ctx, self.frame.size.width - 15, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.frame.size.width - 5, self.frame.size.height - 10, self.frame.size.width - 1, 0);




[AppDel.styleChangerController.RoomHightlightColor setFill];
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);



[super drawRect: rect];
```

Comment: Can you post code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: difference probably is antialiasing. anyway, if you want to have clear lines you must start at half coordinates -> in the middle of pixel. so for example draw line with points [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 10.5]

Comment: I tried doing that and as you can see it works in the uilabel even without the half pixels or quarter pixels for retina. Also ive tried both antiallias on and off